# Umbraco Get Users by User Type

Tags: umbraco

If I have a list of user types (both ID and name), how can I get the users that belong to that user type (not members)?  There doesn't seem to be any methods for `User[] userList = User.Get ByType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using linq you should be able to get what you're looking for. Here's an example of how to get Users based solely on the alias of the User Type:

```
string[] userTypeAliases = new string[] { "writer", "editor" };

var userTypes = umbraco.BusinessLogic.UserType.GetAllUserTypes()
    .Where(ut => userTypeAliases.Contains(ut.Alias));

var users = umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.getAll()
    .Where(u => userTypes.Contains(u.UserType));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using IDs like this:

```
var userType = UserType.GetUserType(1);
var users = User.getAll().Where(u => u.UserType == userType);
```